# Find angle of inclination in $y=\frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^3}{2}+ 3$

Tags: calculus

Given the curve $y = \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^3}{2} + 3$. Find the following:

a) the angle of inclination if $x = 2$

b) the point where the slope is $0$

c) the point where the angle of inclination is $45$ degrees

This is a question from the quiz we had and I didn't get to answer it. I want to know how to solve this. I really don't know how to find the angle of inclination.

Comment: Is that a typo, or are both exponents really supposed to be $3$?

Comment: it's supposed to be a 3. sorry

Answer (score 1):

$a)$ differentiate the equation to get $- \frac{x^2}{2}$. When $2$ is plugged into this equation, one obtains $-2$ as the slope of the tangent line. However, I think you want your answer in degrees, so the answer would be $\tan^{-1}(-2) = -63.34 ^{\circ}$.

$b)$ Now we say for the next part of the question that $-\frac{x^2}{2}= 0$. We find that $\lim_{n \to 0} \frac{-n^2}{2} = 0$, so the point where the slope is zero is at $x = 0$, and hence $(0,3)$.

$c)$ A line with an inclination of $45^{\circ}$ has a slope of $1$, so now we say that $-\frac{x^2}{2}= 1$. This can be easily solved, and is true at $x = -2$. So the point at which the tangent line has an inclination of $45 ^{\circ}$ is $(-2,\frac{13}{3})$.